# merging two dataframe on column and index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi so I have two dataframes, first one is a dataframe which was created by grouping by another df by id (which is index now) and then sorting by 'due' column.

df1:

```
         paid        due    
id          
3     13.000000     5.000000    
2     437.000000    5.000000    
5     90.000000     5.000000    
1     60.000000     5.000000    
4     675.000000    5.000000
```

The other one is a normal dataframe which has 3 columns: 'id' 'name' and 'country'.

df2:

```
id  name       country  
1   'AB'        'DE'
2   'CD'        'DE'
3   'EF'        'NL'
4   'HAH'       'SG'
5   'NOP'      'NOR'
```

So what I was trying to do is to add the 'name' column to the 1st dataframe based on the id number (which is index in first df and column in second one).
So I thought this code would work:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2['name'], left_index=True, right_on='id')
```

But I get error

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Please include the complete error stack trace into your post.

Comment: I added it, please see.

Comment: Which of your databases has which name? I do not see any columns names `'title'`. Please make sure your data is consistent with your code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rename` for map by `dict`:

```
df1['name'] = df1.rename(index=df2.set_index('id')['name']).index
print (df1)
     paid  due   name
id                   
3    13.0  5.0   'EF'
2   437.0  5.0   'CD'
5    90.0  5.0  'NOP'
1    60.0  5.0   'AB'
4   675.0  5.0  'HAH'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find that `pd.concat` is a better option here because it can accept a mix of dataframe and series: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-with-mixed-ndims.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out that I can't really get one column of dataframe in that way but I can remake df2 so that it contains only one needed column:

```
df2=df2[['id', 'name']]
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_on='id')
```

And there is no error anymore.