# Python Pandas copying column from df to another if values same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

**DF ONE:**

```
ID     A    B    C
 1     x    y    z
 1     x    y    z
 2     x    y    z
 2     x    y    z
 2     x    y    z
 3     x    y    z
```

**DF TWO:**

```
ID     D    E    F
 1     a    b    c1
 2     a    b    c2
 3     a    b    c3
```

I want to take column `E` for example from DF TWO, and put it on DF ONE, if the ID is the same, so after I will get this output:

```
ID     A    B    C    F
 1     x    y    z    c1
 1     x    y    z    c1
 2     x    y    z    c2
 2     x    y    z    c2
 2     x    y    z    c2
 3     x    y    z    c3
```

thank you for your help

Comment: You might see my question insightful to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311266/merging-two-dataframe-on-column-and-index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`:

```
d = df2.set_index('ID')['F'].to_dict()
print (d)
{1: 'c1', 2: 'c2', 3: 'c3'}

df1['F'] = df1['ID'].map(d)
print (df1)
   ID  A  B  C   F
0   1  x  y  z  c1
1   1  x  y  z  c1
2   2  x  y  z  c2
3   2  x  y  z  c2
4   2  x  y  z  c2
5   3  x  y  z  c3
```

Another solution is `map` by `Series`:

```
s = df2.set_index('ID')['F']
print (s)
ID
1    c1
2    c2
3    c3
Name: F, dtype: object

df1['F'] = df1['ID'].map(s)
print (df1)
   ID  A  B  C   F
0   1  x  y  z  c1
1   1  x  y  z  c1
2   2  x  y  z  c2
3   2  x  y  z  c2
4   2  x  y  z  c2
5   3  x  y  z  c3
```

**Timings**:

```
#[60000 rows x 5 columns]
df1 = pd.concat([df1]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [115]: %timeit pd.merge(df1, df2[['ID', 'F']],how='left')
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop

In [116]: %timeit df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['F'])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.18 ms per loop

In [117]: %timeit df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['F'].to_dict())
100 loops, best of 3: 3.36 ms per loop

In [118]: %timeit df1['ID'].map({k:v for k, v in df2[['ID', 'F']].as_matrix()})
100 loops, best of 3: 3.44 ms per loop

In [119]: %%timeit 
     ...: df2.index = df2['ID']
     ...: df1['F1'] = df1['ID'].map(df2['F'])
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.33 ms per loop
```

Comment: very nice timing comparison!

Comment: @MaxU - Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create maps from `df2` and you can do it like this:

```
mapping = {k:v for k, v in df2[['ID', 'F']].as_matrix()}
```

Then just apply them to `df1`:

```
df1['F'] = df1['ID'].map(mapping)
```

Or you can use:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['ID', 'F']],how='left')
```

Comment: it works though it takes a lot of time. any idea how to fast it?

Comment: Hmmm, `merge` is slowier as `map`, see `timings` in my answer.

Comment: Very nice :) I always thought that `merge` is preferred technique, also I recall reading `merge` should be very fast but timings have the last word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`, taking care of setting `ID` as index of your dataframe TWO with `df2.index = df2['ID']`:

```
In [10]: df1['F'] = df1['ID'].map(df2['F'])

In [11]: df1
Out[11]: 
   ID  A  B  C   F
0   1  x  y  z  c1
1   1  x  y  z  c1
2   2  x  y  z  c2
3   2  x  y  z  c2
4   2  x  y  z  c2
5   3  x  y  z  c3
```

Comment: not working. maybe it is because `ID` column in my dataframes isn't an index column?

Comment: Yes, you should set it as index in your second dataframe. If you're importing from a .csv file try `pd.read_csv(filename.csv,index_col='ID')`, otherwise set it with `df2.index = df2['ID']`.